# Fisher Exact test in R does not deliver odds ratio

Tags: r, contingency

Regarding fisher's exact test in R... I wonder if I am misunderstanding something.
I have a table with several cells containing 0.

```
structure(list(`Fish group` = c("brain", "eyes", "muscle"), depleted = c(0L, 
33L, 29L), enriched = c(33L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

So I thought it would be ok to use fisher's exact test for this case.
But if I run it, it does not show me parameters such as the odds ratio but it calculates a p-value.

```
fisher.test(dt[,2:3], dt$`Fish group`)
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: I think you need to calculate OR yourself. Fisher's exact test only tests if the contingency table deviates from its expected value.

Comment: From the docs under returned value: "conf.int 
a confidence interval for the odds ratio. Only present in the 2 by 2 case and if argument conf.int = TRUE." You don't have a 2x2 case

Comment: Thanks, yes your are right. There is no way to compute OR for 3 x 2 tables. But is there any way to get kind of post-hoc values? My p-value is significant but how can I evaluate which factors caused this?